# Rails - Conflicts between jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem loading gems into my Rails 4 app.

I use jQuery. In my application.js, I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require html.sortable
//= require disqus_rails
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require main
//= require hammer.min
//= require jquery.animate-enhanced.min
//= require jquery.countTo
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require jquery.fitvids
//= require jquery.magnific-popup.min
//= require jquery.parallax-1.1.3
//= require jquery.properload
//= require jquery.shuffle.modernizr.min
//= require jquery.sudoSlider.min
//= require jquery.superslides.min
//= require masonry.pkgd.min
//= require rotaterator
//= require smoothscrolljs
//= require waypoints.min
//= require wow.min
//= require gmaps/google
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require cocoon
//= require imagesloaded.pkgd.min
//= require isotope.pkgd.min
//= require jquery.counterup.min
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require custom.js
//= require slider
//= require dependent-fields
//= require bootstrap-slider

$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        DependentFields.bind()
    });
});


//= require_tree .
```

In my gem file, I am trying to use rails dependent fields gem. That gem also requires underscore.js.

I think the reason this gem isn't working is because it uses javascript.

I'm having the same problem with the disqus rails gem (which is raising errors that are localhost/:94 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Does anyone know how to resolve conflicts between rails jQuery and javascript?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have set jQuery to work in `noConflict` mode through this line: `$.noConflict();`. jQuery will not define `$` variable globally and will be available through `jQuery` variable only.

```
$.noConflict();   // <=====  HERE  ======
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        DependentFields.bind()
    });
});
```

The "plugins" that are raising this error are probably expecting `$` variable to be set. They should not be doing that however.

**You have 2 options:**

1. Remove `$.noConflict();` line from your `application.js` file.
2. Wrap the code that is raising this error in to a function where `$` is set to `jQuery` variable.

Like this:

```
(function($){
  // Here: $ === jQuery
  // Put js code that raises error here
})(jQuery);
```

---

Also, you are using 2 *document ready* events in your code. You can improve it to this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  DependentFields.bind()
});
```

Comment: I see. You need to go with the first option and remove `$.noConflict();` line. Otherwise, find the gem on GitHub and create a pull request with the improvement.

Comment: I don't understand. Do I wrap the gem in the gem file in the code you suggest as option 1?

Comment: No, forget about everything and just delete this line from your `application.js`: `$.noConflict();`.

Comment: From what you provided, you don't have a conflict. The error message is `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`, which means that a function with the name `$` is not defined. If you remove line `$.noConflict();` from your `application.js` file, it will create a function with that name.

Comment: but that's just one of the .js files in my app/assets/javascripts folder

Comment: I have these conflicts: localhost/:94 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
dependent-fields.self-a2ed82a….js?body=1:70 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
main.self-5888479….js?body=1:316 Uncaught TypeError: dp(...).multipleFilterMasonry is not a function
chrome-extension://mkjojgglmmcghgaiknnpgjgldgaocjfd/content/contentScripts/kwift.CHROME.min.js:1271 Unca

Comment: and that's just one page

Comment: and the js dependent fields does not actually work. I think that's because its dependence is underscore.js which I have in my app/assets/javascripts folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your javascript code where you use $ variable with anonymous function:

```
(function($){

// put your code here

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: When I try that in my underscore.js file, I still can't get the dependent fields rails part working.